# Set up mysql 8 with lower_case_table_names on CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, innodb, centos7

I'm trying to set up a mysql 8 intsall on centos 7 and am having a hell of a time. We have some legacy software that was connecting to old mysql dbs via lowercase names and I want to carry that over to this new setup.

I'm having issues with setting this config properly, I don't know what file to set or when to set it or even what user/permission level to set it under.

When I set it to 1 in /etc/my.cnf then try to start up mysqld I get:

```
[ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('0') and data dictionary ('1').
```

I've reinstalled mysql thinking a fresh start would help with my /etc/my.cnf with the following settings:

```
lower_case_table_names=1
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
bind-address=REDACTED
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

After installing mysql-server and copying the .cnf file to it's spot I run:

```
mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf
```

and am greeted with:

```
2018-10-22T21:30:27.826322Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010139] [Server] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 8161)
2018-10-22T21:30:27.826414Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010142] [Server] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 4000)
2018-10-22T21:30:28.057606Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/be-db-10.lower-test
2018-10-22T21:30:28.057668Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 27077
2018-10-22T21:30:28.060609Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/be-db-10.lower-test
2018-10-22T21:30:28.060628Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/be-db-10.lower-test
2018-10-22T21:30:28.061062Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010187] [Server] Could not open file '/var/log/mysqld.log' for error logging: Permission denied
2018-10-22T21:30:28.061098Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

I assume at some point I royally screwed up some permissions or mysql isn't being fully removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `lower_case_table_names` must be set *before* installing.  The new "Data Dictionary" needs to be constructed *once* with the setting frozen.

So, yes, fully remove, and completely start over (after changing my.cnf).

Comment: Yeah this is what I ended up doing, oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Before the value lower_case_table_names can be changed, unistall mysql on CentOs 7

`yum remove mysql mysql-server`

After uninstall process, rename or delete mysql data

`mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql_backup` (backup) or `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql` (remove)

Install again mysql

`yum install mysql mysql-server`

Before run the mysql server, add `lower_case_table_names=1` on `/etc/my.cnf`, ex: `nano /etc/my.cnf`
Save the file and then start the mysql server with command `systemctl start mysqld`

checking the result can be done with query `SHOW VARIABLES like 'lower%';`

you should get `lower_case_table_names` with value `1`

I hope it can help.

Comment: this did not work for me. And the marked answer is not really helping. After I removed mysql and reinstall it, then change my.cnf and start mysqld, it still shows `lower_case_table_names=0`. Do you have a better instruction?

Comment: Do you started the mysql server before you change my.cnf? you should not start the server before you change the file my.cnf. I don't know why, but I could not change the file either after I started the server. So, install -> change file -> start server. That was my experiment. I hope, it can make you understand clearly.

Comment: The problem is when I do `sudo yum install mysql-server` it will start the server/service automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry, not in my case. after installation, I need to start the mysql server manually, so I have chance to add the configuration. I follow this tutorial, may be it can help you the steps. [How To Install MySQL on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7)